# Elasticsearch dies on primary node at random times. What should I look for in troubleshooting?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 Elasticsearch VM's running (4 GB RAM VM's) and they are configured in 1 cluster with 2 nodes. It's been running fine for months but all of a sudden in the last week the primary node has been just ending with no reason (that I can find).

So when I try to restart the node it takes a while to re-sync but does so eventually.

I have things set to only use 1/2 the RAM on the server and it seems to be doing that but looking at my free memory and HTOP I'm seeing more than that consumed.

My browser-based plugins (Bigdesk, Marvel, elasticsearch-head) also respond very very slowly now. I have noticed that my marvel index files are massive - over 1 GB a day. Can I remove these to improve performance? The marvel data is way more than my actual index/searchable data.

What else can I do to tweak and optimize this system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and hopefully this will help others. Did some other searching as I noticed there were a ton of Marvel indices and they were quite large. I found [Curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator) and ran a delete on indices older than 30 days.

```
﻿curator --host <IP ADDRESS> delete indices --older-than 30 --time-unit days --timestring '%Y.%m.%d'
```

That command purged all the indices over 30 days old and the cluster went green immediately and all plug-ins are working like normal. Granted, I know I'm losing historical data over 30 days but that is ok.

HTH someone else that might be in the same boat.